# get the selected dropdown value in the inputfield instead of placeholder using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want dropdown with radio button which needs to show when I click  field and hide when I click outside and get the selected value in the inputfield. I have partially working code.

1. I am not able to hide the dropdown, once it got opened.
2. I need the selected value in the input field instead of placeholder value which I have.

I see lot of answer's for the select option dropdown but not for the  tag placeholder.

```css
//Not sure why the above function is not hiding the dropdown
RadioDdOnclick() {
  var x=document.getElementById("radiobtn");
  if (x.style.display==="none") {
    document.getElementById('RadioDd').style.visibility='hidden'; //i tried style.display ='none';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('RadioDd').style.display='block';
  }
}
```

```html
<div className="inputWithIcon" onClick={this.RadioDdOnclick} id="radiobtn">
  <input className="inputBlock" id="radioSelect" type="text" placeholder="choose one" />
  <i className="fa fa-angle-down" />
</div>

<div className={ "BudgetRadioDd"} id={ "RadioDd"} style={{display: 'none'}}>
  <fieldset>
    <h4>options to choose</h4>
    <div>
      <label><input type="radio" id="1"/>option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label> <input type="radio" id="2" />option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label><input type="radio" id="3"/>option 3</label>
    </div>

  </fieldset>

</div>
```

```
//css code here
    .input[type=text]{
  width:100%;
  border:2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius:4px;
  margin:8px 0;
  outline:none;
  padding:8px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition:.3s;
}

.inputWithIcon{
  position:relative;
}

.inputWithIcon i{
  position:absolute;
  right: 3%;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 20px 8px;
  color:#c69937;
  transition:.3s;
}
```

**update**
Below answer is working but it is rendering the radio value in another div component.

Looking for better solution..

adding the link to look at the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-feubq6?file=index.js

Comment: Change this  className={"BudgetRadioDd"} id={"RadioDd"} to  className="BudgetRadioDd" id="RadioDd"

Comment: Can you please share the CSS code as well with working classes in HTML without the parenthesis so we can help you?

Comment: With your HTML DOM it's hard to achieve.You need to arrange the DOM first

Comment: @think-twice I dont think the curly braces are prblm here.

Comment: @MuhammadOsama I have css only for arrow position.

Comment: @Ramesh can you please guide me with some examples.

Comment: I understand that but single curly braces act as expressions and having them for hard coded strings doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @think-twice make sense thanks

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code and simplified it to HTML for simplicity. Please check:

```js
function RadioDdOnclick(event) {
  const hovered = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');

  if (hovered[hovered.length - 1].type !== 'radio') {
    const x = document.querySelector('#RadioDd');
    const toggleMap = {
      none: 'block',
      block: 'none'
    };
  
    x.style.display = toggleMap[x.style.display];
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]').forEach(r => {
  r.onclick = _ => {
    if (r.checked) {
      document.querySelector('#radioSelect').value = r.value;
    }
    document.querySelector('#RadioDd').style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="inputWithIcon" id="radiobtn">
  <input className="inputBlock" 
         id="radioSelect" 
         type="text" 
         onClick="RadioDdOnclick(event)" 
         onBlur="RadioDdOnclick(event)" 
         placeholder="choose one" />
  <i className="fa fa-angle-down" />
</div>

<div class="BudgetRadioDd" id="RadioDd" style="display: none">

  <fieldset>
    <h4>options to choose</h4>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input name="budget" type="radio" id="1" value="option 1"/>
        option 1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label> 
        <input name="budget" type="radio" id="2" value="option 2"/>
        option 2
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input name="budget" type="radio" id="3" value="option 3"/>
        option 3
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Andriy I am able to hide the dropdown but it's not rendering the selected dropdown on the inputfield instead of default placeholder.

Comment: I updated my code in the answer, so it updates input field. Please check it

Comment: Hi Andriy, I am getting errors while using the code you provided, attached screenshot above for the references. I am coding in reactjs. Thanks for helping me

Comment: I provided solution in simplified JS and HTML. Please create minimal react example on stackblitz and I will try to help

Comment: Thank you so much Andriy. It was just the curly braces which was misplaced.

Comment: @Andiry one more question. if I want to get multiselect value from dropdown in input field how can I do that?

Comment: I found a bug. when the radio button outside the component is clicked it is rendering that value in the inputfield.  How can I rendering only in the same component radio button is clicked.